# Can we have multiple WITH Clauses in BigQuery and then SELECT by joining

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to have multiple `WITH` clause statements in the BigQuery editor with `#standardSQL`
e.g:

```
#StandardSQL

#features
WITH features AS (
SELECT
fullVisitorId,
IFNULL(totals.bounces, 0) AS bounces,
IFNULL(totals.timeOnSite, 0) AS time_on_site
FROM
`data-to-insights.ecommerce.web_analytics`
WHERE
totals.newVisits = 1
AND date BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20170430');

# features labels
WITH features_label AS ( 
SELECT
fullvisitorid,
IF(COUNTIF(totals.transactions > 0 AND totals.newVisits IS NULL) > 0, 1, 0) AS will_buy_on_return_visit
FROM
`data-to-insights.ecommerce.web_analytics`
GROUP BY fullvisitorid);


# Combine features with feature labels for model training
SELECT * EXCEPT(fullVisitorID)
FROM features
JOIN features_label
USING (fullVisitorId);
```

I am getting errors `Syntax error: Unexpected ";" at [13:44]` but not sure whether the multiple `with` clause works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below

```
WITH features AS (
  SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  IFNULL(totals.bounces, 0) AS bounces,
  IFNULL(totals.timeOnSite, 0) AS time_on_site
  FROM `data-to-insights.ecommerce.web_analytics`
  WHERE totals.newVisits = 1
  AND date BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20170430'
), features_label AS ( 
  SELECT
  fullvisitorid,
  IF(COUNTIF(totals.transactions > 0 AND totals.newVisits IS NULL) > 0, 1, 0) AS will_buy_on_return_visit
  FROM `data-to-insights.ecommerce.web_analytics`
  GROUP BY fullvisitorid
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(fullVisitorID)
FROM features
JOIN features_label
USING (fullVisitorId)
```